# PHP - Failed to load mysql extension

Tags: php, apache, homebrew

OS: Sierra 10.12
PHP Version: 5.6.30

Originally I had a problem with ACPU module, after installing it using homebrew, it did not load properly, I used this article:

https://gist.github.com/andrewstobbe/7c56de552df41e444f0a1d5bdfa02ffe

And more specifically, I change line in httpd.conf file from this:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

to this:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

ACPU, Xdebug and rest of modules works properly and they are visible in phpinfo(), but when I try to run one of projects, i've got an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

UPDATE:

I know that I should use mysqli instead, but i can't change this right now, mysql loads fine and works properly with original line in httpd.conf (`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`)

Comment: Good, you shouldn't be using [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Make use of [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Look at my update in post

Comment: I'm not a Mac expert, but I notice that the page you refer to includes lines like `brew reinstall php56-apcu` for most of the extensions you could want, but not a line for the `-mysql` extension (probably because nobody would expect to actually want to install that extension any more). Did you try simply adding a line similar to the others but for that extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`brew reinstall php56 --with-libmysql`